# Openstreetmap's limitation in usage policy

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I am using openstreetmap's Nominatim service in order to add a map in my website, on which the users can select their location. But there are some limitations in their usage policy and more specifically they require no heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second).
Is there any way that I can prioritize the requests that will be sent on the same second or add them in some kind of queue, so that no request is lost?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to build that yourself, using some sort of FIFO queue receiving requests to be sent to OSM and then firing them off one every 1.5 seconds or so (bit slower than the limit just to be sure).

Of course that means whatever is calling your method that does the calls to OSM has be be able to work with potentially long delays in getting its results.

Answer (score 1):

Nominatim is open source. Apart from OSM's Nominatim instance there are other [third-party instances](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers) available with different usage limits. And of course you can [install your own Nominatim instance](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/) which won't have any usage limitations.